# How To Create Multiple Players with Python VLC and Have Different Volumes on Them?

Tags: python, audio, vlc, audio-player, python-vlc

I am trying to mix two .mp3 songs together by simply changing the volumes of two songs, similar to DJing. However, when I set the volume of a player, both players' volumes are being changed to the value that I've last set. I would like to create two separate players that have different volume properties AKA for example to have one player with volume(100) and the other set to volume(20). Here is how I am doing it:

```
import vlc
import time

# Path for mp3 file
song = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Projects/Music Shit/Martin Garrix - Animals (Original Mix).mp3'

# Set up and play player with volume 100
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(song)
media = vlc.Media(song)
player.set_media(media)
player.audio_set_volume(100)
player.play()

# Path for second mp3 file
song2 = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Projects/Music Shit/Tremor (Sensation 2014 Anthem).mp3'

# Set up and play second player with volume 20
player2 = vlc.MediaPlayer(song2)
media2 = vlc.Media(song2)
player2.set_media(media2)
player2.audio_set_volume(20)
player2.play()
```

When I run this, both songs play at volume 20, which is undesired. I believe that they are linked to one player, which I do not want. I'd like to have two separate players with different volumes.

By the way when I tried this on Mac it worked, and the audio had different volumes, but I am currently on Windows and it is not working. Seems weird!

Any help would be much appreciated. It's my first time submitting a question!

Answer (score 1):

A variation on a theme, using multiple instances of `vlc.Instance` is the way to go.

```
import vlc
import time

files = ['./V2.mp4','./vp1.mp3','./V3.mp4'] 
instances = []
medias = []
players = []


for idx, fname in enumerate(files):
    print("Loading",fname)
    instances.append(vlc.Instance())
    medias.append(instances[idx].media_new(fname))
    time.sleep(1) # used solely to gauge the difference in volumes
    players.append(vlc.MediaPlayer())
    players[idx].set_media(medias[idx])
    players[idx].play() 

players[1].audio_set_volume(120)
players[2].audio_set_volume(80)
player_count = players # copy of the players list so we don't modify during iteration
still_playing = True
time.sleep(0.5) # Wait for players to start

while still_playing:
    time.sleep(1)
    for p in players:
        if p.is_playing():
            continue
        else:
            player_count.remove(p)
            players = player_count # no point iterating over players that have finished
            print("Finished - Still playing ", str(len(player_count)))

    if len(player_count) != 0:
        continue
    else:
        still_playing = False
```

Comment: This does not work on Linux Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @xuancong84 I am happy to report that on Linux, 4 years later, `this does still work`. Each instance plays at the volume it was assigned.

Comment: It is Raspberry Pi 4's problem, it should work on PC Linux. The RPI does not have a hardware mixer, so everything have only 1 volume.

Comment: @xuancong84 I am glad to hear that you found the reason, even if you didn't find a solution. Maybe these links will help but I'm no expert. https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-audio-boards-for-your-hi-fi-projects/ https://github.com/nooploop/piejam

Comment: in my recent smart-home project, the workaround solution is to use another program such as `mplayer`, `mpg123`, `mpg321`, etc., they can play at a different volume from VLC's volume. However, if I run another instance of VLC (even if it is cvlc), it does not work. So the problem is that all VLC intances on Raspberry Pi unnecessarily share the same volume. And therefore, it is still VLC's bug for this particular platform.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem really interesting, so I downloaded the `vlc` python module and tinkered with it, and I think I found a solution for you.

What I did is I built an *array* containing the VLC instances, I built a function that creates VLC instances, and a loop that makes sure they're running (and produces verbose output).

This does require you make sure that your VLC player allows multiple window instances.

My code:

```
import vlc
import time

VLCObjects = []

def VLCInstance(src, volume):
    
    # creating vlc media player object 
    try:
        vlc_instance = vlc.Instance() 
        player = vlc_instance.media_player_new() 
        media = vlc_instance.media_new(src)
        player.set_media(media)
    except:
        return("Error: Was unable to mount media")
    else:
        pass
    
    VLCObjects.append(player)

    VLCObjects[0].audio_set_volume(volume) 
    VLCObjects[0].play() 

    # give time to initialize, then get length of audio & wait until done playing
    time.sleep(1) 
    duration = VLCObjects[0].get_length() 
    #time.sleep(duration)
    return("Success: Song playing")
```

Then you'd make all your calls or whatever here, and then the loop:

```
song1 = ...
song2 = ...
VLCInstance(song1, 100)
VLCInstance(song2, 20)
```

```
while(True):

    playing = False
    
    time.sleep(1) 
    
    print(VLCObjects)
    for x in range(0, len(VLCObjects) ):
        value = VLCObjects[x].is_playing()

        if value == True:
            print("... VLCObject #%d is playing" % x)
            playing = True
            
        else:
            print("... VLCObject #%d needed to be restarted" % x)
            VLCObjects[x].play()
            
    if playing == False:
        break
```

The resulting output will look something like this, and there will be two non-windowed VLC players.

```
Success: Song playing
Success: Song playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
0
0
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
[<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271520>, <vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7fa56d271cd0>]
... VLCObject #0 is playing
... VLCObject #1 is playing
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do it for me. When I call song2 with volume(20), both tracks have set their volume to 20. I am on windows 7 with Python 3.8.5. It's weird that it worked fine for me on a Mac. Do you know what the issue is here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue you're having is, but I would try adding a second `if, else` block into the `while` loop to check if the volume is what was originally called for. You'd just need another array, maybe `VLCVolumes` at the beginning, and for the value to be saved when you call the `VLCInstance` function. 

I hope that fixes the problem for you!

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint 20 (Cinnamon 4.6.6) on a Samsung laptop, also running 3.8.5

Comment: This does not work on Linux either.